# Getting exception when creating AlertDialog android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat, illegalstateexception

I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

And it appears when my ErrorDialogFragment is doing `builder.create();`

Here is my ErrorDialogFragment code:

```
public class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    String message = getArguments().getString("message");


    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_error, null);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    TextView tvMessage = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
    Button btnOk = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

    tvTitle.setText(title);
    tvMessage.setText(message);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setView(dialogView);

    return builder.create();
}

}
```

The activity that calls the ErrorDialogFragment extends `Activity` and I need it fullscreen with the theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`. And need that theme else the UI Works in an odd way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the theme in the Activity rather than in the Application, in your manifest?

Comment: Can you show the layout file for `R.layout.dialog_error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.app.DialogFragment` instead of `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`.

Comment: you could have asked this in a comment.

Comment: this was the problem. I was using android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog, not directly android.app.DialogFragment. Thanks!!!